# How to use the filter?

Tags: nextpage

How to use the filter, before WordPress converts `<!--nextpage-->`?

The following construction does not work:

```
add_filter ( "the_content", function( $content ) {

  $content = preg_replace( "/(\<\!--nextpage--\>)/miu", htmlspecialchars( $1, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false ), $content );

  return $content;

});
```

Code just for example.

Comment: What's the end goal here or what are you trying to achieve?